why font size changed with a different pc with same resolution when using plotly dash?
I am using plotly dash with CSS to build my dashboard. I am using CSS to define font style. I changed to a different pc from windown 10 to windows 11 but with same screen resolution of 1600 by 900.
The font size is defined by pixel like below. so why displayed font size change when changing different pc with same resolution? How to keep the diplay font size if I go to different pc with even different screen resolution? Thanks
.top-button {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size:12px;
}


One reason could be that the font-family specified for this element is not available on one of your pc and fallbacks to another one that looks different in size for the same font-size. You can check the actual styles that are applied on .top-button element(s) in dev tools (ie. in the "Elements" pane, check "Styles" and "Computed").

Thanks Eric, I checked and it doesn't show font- family.

Is using 'vw' better than using 'px'?

It's not worse or better, vw is relative to the viewport width, ie. 1vw represents 1% of the window width so it's responsive. Are you sure the styles above are applied properly ? Maybe you could add to your question a mwe with the app init and the relevant part of the layout (or just a container with the component(s) on which you want to add the class top-button).
